# How to bevel something on only some faces?

Tags: bevel

I want to bevel on the side edge(red arrow) but not up at the top part(blue arrow)
[image: The object/edge that i am beveling]

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine how that would even look? If you bevel only the side edge then the edges presumably won't meet? Or you reduce the dimension of the top edge?

Answer (score 6):

[image: New Edge Loop just below current one]

Its sort of unavoidable.  You'll need to transition from the single edge (above) to the split/beveled edge (below) somehow.

If you want the bevel to only be on the vertical part, you can add an edge loop (highlighted) just below the current knee joint, and then select the edge below the edge loop and just bevel that. Then the 'fan' that transitions from no-bevel to bevel will be on the vertical edge.